# c#: Asp.net WebApi default route to index.html

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create an Asp.net WebApi / Single Page Application. I would like my server to dispense index.html if no route is given. I would like it to use a controller when one is specified in the normal "{controller}/{id}" fashion.

I realized that I can visit my index page by using http://localhost:555/index.html. How do I do the same by visiting http://localhost:555 ?

Comment: if asp.net core
just add: app.UseDefaultFiles();
in Startup.cs Configure method.

Answer (score 9):

Just add a route to your WebApiConfig file for index page. Your method should look like this:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Attribute routing
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Route to index.html
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Index",
                routeTemplate: "{id}.html",
                defaults: new {id = "index"});

            // Default route
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to create an empty **DefaultRoute**.

```
// I think this passes control through before trying to use a Controller
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultRoute", "");

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultAPI",
    "{controller}/{id}",
    new { Controller = "Home", Id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Another solution was to prefix my **WebApi** with 'api', which is not entirely what I wanted, but is a suitable solution. This was shown in Herman Guzman's answer, but is not his answer.

```
// Default route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For ASP.NET Core users**

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [app.UseDefaultFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.defaultfilesextensions.usedefaultfiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to achieve this. The method adds a [rewriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.rewritebuilderextensions.userewriter?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that rewrites requests to the default route `"/"` to `/index.html`. For this to work, it is important that you place this line before `.UseStaticFiles()`. Example:

```
// ...
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

There is a good blog post that describes how this works in detail: [Blog Post](https://blog.steadycoding.com/usedefaultfiles-usestaticfiles-usespastaticfiles-usespa/)